# How to make type aliases based on compile flags in Rust?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

I want to alias the type `uint` to `u32` by default, but a flag can be set during compilation to change it to `usize`. The code should be something like this:

```
#[cfg(uint='u32') || default]
type uint = u32;
#[cfg(uint='usize')]
type uint = u64;
```

And when I compile, I can use `cargo build --uint=usize`. What should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feature you want doesn't exist.  There are a few ways to fake it.

First, you can use features:

```
#[cfg(all(feature="uint-is-u16", not(any(feature="uint-is-u32", feature="uint-is-u64"))))]
type uint = u16;
#[cfg(not(any(feature="uint-is-u16", feature="uint-is-u64")))]
type uint = u32;
#[cfg(all(feature="uint-is-u64", not(any(feature="uint-is-u16"))))]
type uint = u64;
```

These are specified using `cargo build --features=uint-is-u64`.  Note that features are *strictly* additive, and you *cannot* make "exclusive" features: *i.e.* you can't make it impossible to specify both `u64` and `u32`.  As such, you need to structure the code such that it works even if multiple features are enabled.

Alternately, you could put the setting in a configuration file somewhere, and write a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) that emits the type alias as code (see the [code generation example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#case-study-code-generation)).