# How to implement a `rocket::request::FromRequest` to a tuple struct?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket, tuple-struct

TLDR;

Is it possible to implement `rocket::request::FromRequest` in a tuple struct? (Or is it called newtype idiom?)

```rust
#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
pub struct IpAddWrapper(std::net::SocketAddr);


#[cfg(any(not(target_os = "windows"), feature = "integration_test"))]
pub struct IpAddWrapper(IpAddr);

pub struct IpAddr<'r>(&'r str);

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl<'r> FromRequest<'r> for IpAddr<'r> {
    type Error = &'r str;
    
    async fn from_request(request: &'r Request<'_>) -> Outcome<Self, Self::Error> {
        let keys: Vec<_> = request.headers().get("X-Real-IP").collect();
        match keys.len() {
            0 => Outcome::Failure((Status::NotFound, "IP Address not found")),
            1 => Outcome::Success(IpAddr(keys[0])),
            _ => Outcome::Failure((Status::NotFound, "Indeterminable Error")),
        }
    }
}
```

In my `Cargo.toml`

```
...

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["json"]}
...
```

---

Context, if you're interested

I have 3 types of compilation of a middleware for testing

(1) In Ubuntu and/or running integration tests
(2) Windows, whilst running the GUI app in Java
(3) Windows, to run integration tests

My goal is to get the IP Address of the HTTP request from the client app or the GUI app

For some reason (which means I don't exactly know the reason), if I use as a function parameter/argument the `std::net::SocketAddr` type, running (2), I easily get the IP Address on a request, even if there's no header explicitly inserted in the GUI app's request (I think *gson-2.6.2.jar* took care of that).

But running (1) (in correspondence with *nginx*) and (3) (using `use rocket::local::blocking::Client`), using the same function with a parameter/argument of `std::net::SocketAddr`, I encounter problems.

The solution I used for now is to make the IP Address explicit in the client's side with

```java
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// in GET
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
// IN POST
// con.setRequestMethod("POST");

con.setRequestProperty("api-key", http.APISECRET);
con.setRequestProperty("ContentType", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("X-Real-IP", "0.0.0.0");
```

But I'm curious if the question I asked above is possible and I'm just experiencing technical issues due to inexperience.

Thanks for reading.

---

**INDIRECT ANSWER**

The solution I have for now, which doesn't answer my question, but it's something that I think is "clean". Thanks to @cameron1024's comment, I did some searching and found [this](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/src/rocket/request/from_request.rs.html#417-426), and used snippets of codes over there and now I have a new code structure, not needing conditional compilation anymore

```rust
#[post("/index?<c>&<a>", rank = 1)]
fn some_post(
    _key: ApiKey,
    remote_addr: IpAddr,
    c: String,
    a: String,
) -> Result<(), ErrorResponse> { ... }


pub struct IpAddr(String);

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl<'r> FromRequest<'r> for IpAddr {
    type Error = &'r str;
    async fn from_request(request: &'r Request<'_>) -> Outcome<Self, Self::Error> {
        match request.remote() {
            Some(addr) => Outcome::Success(IpAddr(addr.to_string())),
            None => {
                let keys: Vec<_> = request.headers().get("X-Real-IP").collect();
                match keys.len() {
                    0 => Outcome::Failure((Status::NotFound, "IP Address not found")),
                    1 => Outcome::Success(IpAddr(keys[0].to_string())),
                    _ => Outcome::Failure((Status::NotFound, "Indeterminable Error")),
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And also on the Java GUI & HTTP client app, I don't have to use the code above

```java
con.setRequestProperty("X-Real-IP", "0.0.0.0");
```

That I have to comment out when compiling it for deployment.
Woohoo!

---

**MY ACCEPTED SOLUTION**
*but still not answering the post question*

My problem with the **indirect answer** (above) is that there will always be one unnecessary step in determining the IP address, either prioritizing checking of the header "X-Real-IP" first or the `std::net::SocketAddr`. And also it might be another opportunity for attackers since there’s two allowable header keys for IP addresses, and in deployment, only a single header key is accepted: "X-Real-IP".

So I sought for other solutions and thought about type aliasing and used this SO answer: [How to make type aliases based on compile flags in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50981221/8558585)

The following is my current code:

```rust
// guards.rs
#[cfg(all(target_os = "windows", not(feature = "integration_test")))]
pub type IpAddrAlias = std::net::SocketAddr;

#[cfg(any(not(target_os = "windows"), feature = "integration_test"))]
pub type IpAddrAlias<'r> = IpAddr<'r>;

pub struct IpAddr<'r>(&'r str);

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl<'r> FromRequest<'r> for IpAddr<'r> {
    type Error = &'r str;

    async fn from_request(request: &'r Request<'_>) -> Outcome<Self, Self::Error> {
        let keys: Vec<_> = request.headers().get("X-Real-IP").collect();
        match keys.len() {
            0 => Outcome::Failure((Status::NotFound, "IP Address not found")),
            1 => Outcome::Success(IpAddr(keys[0])),
            _ => Outcome::Failure((Status::NotFound, "Indeterminable Error")),
        }
    }
}

// main.rs
mod utils;
use utils::guards::{ApiKey, UserAgent, IpAddrAlias};

#[post("/index?<c>&<a>", rank = 1)]
fn some_post(
    _key: ApiKey,
    remote_addr: IpAddrAlias,
    c: String,
    a: String,
) -> Result<Redirect, ErrorResponse> { ... }
```

Still woohoo for Rust!

Comment: There's some issues with the code you wrote, most importantly, `IpAddr<'r>` has a lifetime annotation, but you've put it in a struct without any lifetime annotations. Can you explain a bit what issue you're having with your current implementation. But in general, you should be able to write a `FromRequest` impl that first tries to read it from a header, and then calls `SocketAddr`'s `FromRequest` impl

Comment: Oh yeah, I can change the `IpAddr<'r>` type if need be, thanks for pointing that out.

I'm attempting to have a tuple struct, that has a single element (`self.0`), that contains different types (having `std::net::SocketAddr`, and my custom type of `IpAddr`). The types of which would vary depending on some conditions when I compile it.

Could you demonstrate what you mean by "and then calls `SocketAddr`'s `FromRequest` impl"?

Comment: Oh and uhm the `IpAddWrapper` would then be used as a parameter for a function that handles request. something like:

```fn some_post(_key: ApiKey, remote_addr: IpAddWrapper, c: String) -> Result<Redirect, ErrorResponse> { ... }```

Comment: Your comment made me think and I found out about this [FromRequest](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/request/trait.FromRequest.html#impl-FromRequest%3C%27a%2C%20%27r%3E-for-SocketAddr), I overlooked this segment before. And I looked up its source code and I'll try to model and tinker with that. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, you can just call `SocketAddr::from_request()` (as long as the trait is in scope). It returns an `Outcome` (which is like a `Result` except it has a `Redirect` variant) so you can handle any errors nicely